# gulp watch in laravel elixir not working globule.js undefined indexof

Tags: laravel, gulp, watch, laravel-elixir

I have a Laravel project in Ubuntu 16.04.

It is an existing project where the gulpfile.js is working properly on another system.

My problem is the gulp watch is not working at only this error is showing up:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/globule/lib/globule.js:25:16
at Array.reduce (native)
at processPatterns (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/globule/lib/globule.js:24:30)
at Object.globule.find (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/globule/lib/globule.js:76:17)
at Gaze.add (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:174:19)
at new Gaze (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:74:10)
at gaze (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:86:10)
at Object.module.exports [as watch] (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/glob-watcher/index.js:12:17)
at Gulp.watch (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/index.js:40:14)
at /home/vagrant/votingmp/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/recipes/watch.js:26:18
```

Has anybody ever had the same problem? I can't seem to find any solution regarding this

```
Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/globule/lib/globule.js:25:16
```

Any helps appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with you, then I realize that one of my script files gen errors, so just remove it from `mix.scripts([])` array, unless please check your gulp.js content.